# How to enable accessibility for GTK applications running as root?

Tags: 20.04, gtk, accessibility, policykit, onscreen-keyboard

I have a graphical application on Ubuntu 20.04 that is run with pkexec to properly get necessary root access. Many users will need the on-screen keyboard for this app, however I noticed that GTK apps will only display the OSK when **not** run as root. (sudo gedit doesn't work either)

How can I use the OSK when running a gtk app as root through pkexec?
I'm aware of onboard, but would prefer to inherit the Gnome OSK if possible.

**EDIT:**
I ended up using a script that first checks if the user's GNOME OSK is enabled, then launches Onboard for the duration of the program (passed as arg):

```
/usr/bin/my-program $(pkexec --user myUser gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-keyboard-enabled)
```

I tried sudo -E and there is no pkexec equivalent. Couldn't get it working.

Comment: Looks to me like a [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): Why do you need to run an application as root in the first place?

Comment: It modifies network + system files. I'm aware it's best to avoid running graphical apps as root if possible, but I understand pkexec to be an accepted method to do so.

Comment: Try "sudo -E ". To run as root your app.